# Why does an UPDATE to a full-text-indexed column lock the full text index?

Tags: sql-server, locking, full-text-search, sql-server-2017

I'm troubleshooting a deadlock on a SQL Server full-text index. From what I can see in SentryOne's monitoring, two queries deadlocked when trying to acquire locks on the full-text index; one query was an `UPDATE <indexed table> SET <indexed column>=<some value>`, the other query looks like automatic population of the full-text index. What I don't understand is why the `UPDATE` needed the lock; as I understand [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/populate-full-text-indexes?view=sql-server-2017#population-based-on-change-tracking), the index should be populated asynchronously, not as part of the `UPDATE` query. Can anyone clear up why this lock was necessary?

Comment: Depends on what page or leaf is being locked to make this adjustment. If you have the “other” query, that might help

Comment: @clifton_h I don't have the text of the other query; SentryOne doesn't show it. I'm really just guessing that it's the automatic population of the index, because I don't know what else it could be.